# Горизонтальный скролл в адаптивной таблице на iPhone

Tags: html, css

Всем добрый день! У меня в общем маленькая проблемка, я сделал таблицу с прайсом в адаптивном виде. Когда я уменьшаю браузер до *320рх*, то горизонтальный скролл видно, а когда захожу с телефона (iPhone5) то ползунка не видно, но сама прокрутка сенсором работает. Хотелось бы добиться того, чтобы ползунок все-таки был видимым на телефоне, иначе посетитель не будет знать что, чтобы посмотреть инфу в таблице, нужно поскролить влево.

Answer (score 2):

Рабочий код для вебкит-браузеров:

```css
html, body, div {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div {
    height:200%;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 12px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 12px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

> Источник: [Make scrollbar visible in mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907777/make-scrollbar-visible-in-mobile-browsers)